# Hazelcast memory is continuously increasing

Tags: memory, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast cluster with two machines.

The only object in the cluster is a map. Analysing the log files I noticed that the health monitor starts to report a slow increase in memory consumption even though no new entries are being added to map (see sample of log entries below)

Any ideas of what may be causing the memory increase?

---

```
<p>2015-09-16 10:45:49 INFO  HealthMonitor:? - [10.11.173.129]:5903
[dev] [3.2.1] memory.used=97.6M, memory.free=30.4M,
memory.total=128.0M, memory.max=128.0M, memory.used/total=76.27%,
memory.used/max=76.27%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=1.00%,
load.systemAverage=3.00%, thread.count=96, thread.peakCount=107,
event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0,
executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0,
executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
operations.remote.size=1, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=2,
clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=2,
connection.count=2</p>

<p>2015-09-16 10:46:02 INFO 
InternalPartitionService:? - [10.11.173.129]:5903 [dev] [3.2.1]
Remaining migration tasks in queue =    51 2015-09-16 10:46:12 DEBUG
TeleavisoIvrLoader:71 - Checking for new files... 2015-09-16 10:46:13
INFO  InternalPartitionService:? - [10.11.173.129]:5903 [dev] [3.2.1]
All migration tasks has been completed, queues are empty. 2015-09-16
10:46:19 INFO  HealthMonitor:? - [10.11.173.129]:5903 [dev] [3.2.1]
memory.used=103.9M, memory.free=24.1M, memory.total=128.0M,
memory.max=128.0M, memory.used/total=81.21%, memory.used/max=81.21%,
load.process=0.00%, load.system=1.00%, load.systemAverage=2.00%,
thread.count=73, thread.peakCount=107, event.q.size=0,
executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0,
executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0,
executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=2,
clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=2,
connection.count=2</p>

<p>2015-09-16 10:46:49 INFO  HealthMonitor:? - [10.11.173.129]:5903
[dev] [3.2.1] memory.used=105.1M, memory.free=22.9M,
memory.total=128.0M, memory.max=128.0M, memory.used/total=82.11%,
memory.used/max=82.11%, load.process=0.00%, load.system=1.00%,
load.systemAverage=1.00%, thread.count=73, thread.peakCount=107,
event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0,
executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0,
executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, proxy.count=2,
clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=2,
connection.count=2</p>
```

Comment: Is the map being used? Are entries added ? What is the configuration of the map? Perhaps it is related to expiration... items are added.. and eventually expired..

Comment: I see that you have very little memory in your jvm.. 128mb!

Comment: @pveentjer, I think this is the amount of memory that hazelcast has allocated for its own needs, usually that is a subset of the entire RAM of the machine. I have personally seen less than 1GB to be present in `memory.total` and `memory.max` on a node that operated on 12GB physical memory.

Comment: @FernandaCoulaud, do you see an increase in the following values `thread.count`, and  `thread.peakCount` as well? It could indicate locking issues, that lead to allocation of more and more threads for hazelcast to use. It would help if you provide us code snippets of how you operate with hazelcast, how and when you put and get data from it and etc.